# How to copy a row and past in different table using HQL

Tags: java, hql

Table name:- main

```
id | Code | Name |  total  
-------------------------
01 | m-01 | bag  | 6    |
02 | m-02 | pen  | 3    |
03 | m-01 | bag  | 4    |
```

Table name:- duplicate

```
id | Code | Name | total  
------------------------
01 | m-01 | bag  | 6   |
03 | m-01 | hen  | 4   |
```

Here I want select row where code is 'm-01' and past into another Table whose name is duplicate.
I am using JDK Compliance

> JavaSE-1.8

and

> JavaEE IDE

I Use it but get error in run time.

> BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination);//but get sum error.

Comment: Have a look at how to write a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *Which* BeanUtils are you using, org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils or org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils? They have source and destination inverted compared with each other, `(src, dst)` only applies for the spring variant!